# if the library had/has an opening

Tags: subjunctive-mood

I'm wondering whether 'has' or 'had' is appropriate in the following 
dialogue:

John: I'd like to find a job on campus. If the library has/had an opening, 
that'd be great.

Mary: Let's see. I'm sorry. All the positions have been filled.

I suspect that the frequent use of 'had' to indicate counterfactuality 
leads some people to prefer 'has', as it leaves open the possibility 
that such an opening exists, rather than refuting it altogether.

I'd appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

'has' is definitely more appropriate in that case. However, one could use 'had' in a context like the following:

> I was wondering if the library had an opening

'has' would work there too, but only 'has' works in the case of your particular sentence

Comment: What's your reason for opting for 'has'?

Answer (score 0):

If it had been a reference to the past, then *If the library had had an opening* would have been used. I think either *had* or *has* in the original conveys the intended message.

Comment: The context of the dialogue shows John wants a job in the library. Wouldn't the use of 'had' sound odd to you?

Comment: @Apollyon No, I frequently hear (but do not say) things such as *I wonder if the library had an opening* (if talking to a library official) to refer to the present.